# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - libreconv

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.2

I am new to 'libreconv' gem, 
I am using Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.0 version 
While I am converting Ms Word document to PDF, I get following error:

2.2.0 > Libreconv.convert('sample1.doc', '/Users/rp/test_document.pdf')

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/sample1.pdf
from /home/rp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:1391:in `initialize'

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403667/no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sysopen-public-receipts-416981-pdf) worked for me

Comment: actually the problem is persisting for me.

Comment: Any solution to this? This occurs with me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with such patch:

```
class Libreconv::Converter
  alias_method :old_convert, :convert

   def convert
     if Rails.env.development?
       old_convert
     else
       %x(sudo #{@soffice_command} --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir #{@target_path} #{@source})
       target_tmp_file = "#{@target_path}/#{File.basename(@source, ".*")}.pdf"
       FileUtils.cp target_tmp_file, @target
     end
   end
end
```