# Files in public directory in Rails - Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, controller

I'm currently working on a Rails 5.2 application using the [combine pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) gem. I'm trying to merge two PDF files but somehow I'm unable to load files from the `public` directory.

In the controller I have the following method:

```
def pdf_download
  pdf = CombinePDF.new
  pdf << CombinePDF.load("#{Rails.root}/public/pdfs/1.pdf") 
  pdf << CombinePDF.load("#{Rails.root}/public/pdfs/1.pdf")
  pdf.save "combined.pdf"

  send_data combined_file.to_pdf, filename: "combined.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
end
```

I have tried many posts on StackOverflow without success such as using [Rails.root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403667/no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sysopen-public-receipts-416981-pdf). But I still get the same error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - app/public/pdfs/1.pdf):
```

Is there any additional configuration I have to do to load files from `public`? and if these PDF shouldn't be in `public` where should I store them?

Comment: Why does one example start with `#{Rails.root}/` and the other with `./`? What is your actual code? Where do the files actually exist?

Comment: The code you've written is clearly different to the code in the error message. Can you please verify which version of the code you're running, and show the corresponding error (if there is one!)

Comment: if these PDF shouldn't be in public where should I store them? 
Answer is you can upload your file on amazon s3 and can use active storage

Comment: @tom-lord my apologies by mistake I uploaded the wrong image. However, I got passed this issue but wondering if theres a more optimal solution. Please feel free to comment on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

```
  def pdf_download
    pdf = CombinePDF.new
    pdf << CombinePDF.load(Rails.root.join("public", "pdfs/1.pdf").to_s)
    pdf << CombinePDF.load(Rails.root.join("public", "pdfs/2.pdf").to_s)
    # pdf.save "combined.pdf"

    send_data pdf.to_pdf, filename: "combined.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

```
pdf << CombinePDF.load("./public/pdfs/1.pdf")
```